# Fireworks Text Glossy Effect

Tags: text, adobe-fireworks

I am applying a simple glossy effect over some text using Fireworks.

I am doing this by partially placing an ellipse over the text (see image)

How can I adjust this so that the ellipse is cropped apart from where it covers the text?

[image: two muppets]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this link can help you...

http://www.calvinshub.com/2008/10/creating-a-web-20-glossy-text-effect-in-fireworks/